# Php-Di annotations performance

Tags: php, php-di

Can anyone explain me what is better regarding performace in Php-Di? 
Using `annotations` or `plain constructor params`? 
Annotations = less chars to write but is it a good practice?

```
class A {
    /**
    * @Inject
    * @var B
    **/
    private $b;

    use() {
        $this->b->method();
    }
}
```

Vs:

```
class A {
    /** @var B **/
    private $b;

    public function __constructor(B $b) {
        $this->b=$b;
    }

    use() {
        $this->b->method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the time its all depends on your preferences,
I personally like the 2nd approach

Answer (score 2):

Annotations are, like autowiring which is based on PHP's reflection, cached. So it doesn't matter which one you use, you will get the same performances.

You can read the ["Performance" documentation](http://php-di.org/doc/performances.html) to learn more about caching.